# useEffect se ejecuta múltiples veces

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tengo un problema con el hook useffect. Lo que pasa es que cuando quiero hacer un fetch al renderizar un componente este se ejecuta multiples veces.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que hago es lo siguiente:

```
      let getDataTable = async () => {
        try {
            fetch("http://localhost:3002/api/v1/Login", {
                method: "POST",
                mode: "cors",
                cache: "no-cache",
                credentials: "same-origin",
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                  UserName: "TEST",
                  Password: "2022",
                  CompanyDB: "TEST",
                }),
              });
        }
         catch (error) {
          }
      };

      useEffect(() => {
        getDataTable();
      }, []);
```

Intenté hacer el fetch dentro del useEffect pero es lo mismo, lo hace multiples veces y no entiendo aún el problema. Estoy usando NextJS.

Comment: Con este código que veo no veo porque se ejecute más veces, lo mejor sería que pusieras el componente entero para ver que puede estar pasando

Answer (score 0):

Un problema de esto es que tu componente se esta renderizando multiples veces, puedes remover el strictmode para evitar esto, y de igual manera recomiendo usar el useCallback el cual te hace controlar mejor cuando renderizar una funcion en especifico:

```
  let getDataTable = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
        fetch("http://localhost:3002/api/v1/Login", {
            method: "POST",
            mode: "cors",
            cache: "no-cache",
            credentials: "same-origin",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              UserName: "TEST",
              Password: "2022",
              CompanyDB: "TEST",
            }),
          });
    }
     catch (error) {
      }
  },[])

  useEffect(() => {
    getDataTable();
  }, []);
```

Espero te sirva amigo.